# SVN successful commit not showing on website

Tags: asp.net, svn, windows-server-2003, visualsvn

**Background**

I have an installation of VisualSVN on a server. under this, I have a basic repository (no branches/trunks or tags). I used svn in it's most basic format as I was the only developer on it.

The project itself is an IIS ASP.NET 3.5 website hosted at d:\website1. I can access this development site at `http://devserver/`

The respository can be accessed at `http://devserver:8888/`

Any changes I make using visual studio 2010/notepad++ etc were immediately reflected on the website, whether I had committed the changes or not. This worked well for me.

**Problem**

However there is another developer who now needs to make changes to a certain section of the website.

I have set up a user with Read/Write capabilities in VisualSVN, and all works well there, they can grab the code, make changes and commit those changes. However their changes are not reflected on the website, even though they are showing in both the repository and file system.

The changes only show when I do an update, and not when the other user updates.

**SVN n00b**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your web site serves files from your working copy of the project. So obviously, if another developer makes changes in his own working copy, or even commits to SVN, the web site will only see the changes once you update your working copy.

You should create a working copy for the web site itself, which would have the latest committed files from subversion, and not intermediate changes which have not been committed yet.

And each developer should have its own server serving file from his own working copy to test changes before committing them.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow. The website serves from a single location - the devserver, myself and the other developer both access the files across the network. Why would it be serving file from my working copy, when that copy is the currently running website?

Comment: Then that is another serious problem. Don't share a single working copy between two developers. Else what's the point in using Subversion?

Comment: well like i mentioned, it was fine for what i needed it for (as the only user) for the past 2 years.

Comment: Yes, but things have changed now. So you should change how you work. Each developer should have its own working copy, and its own development server. If you need some kind of "official" server for testers, for example, then create a third working copy, which gets updated each time a commit is made.

Comment: thanks for the useful comments, are there any good resources on how to do these things, specifically updating a 3rd working copy on commit hook?

Comment: The SVN book, of course: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks